# logstash loki logs namespace, containers, pod is not showing properly

Tags: logstash, grafana-loki

Im running logstash inside kubernetes, i have another pods is generating random logs constantly. Grafana is able to detect the loki driver and labels, but the namespace, pod, containers name is not showing in grafana.

[image]
if u see the grafana only host, path and type are listed, it is not picking like containers, pods, namespaces.

> logstash conf

```
 input {
      file {
        id => "varlog"
        path => "/var/log/containers/"
        type => "var log"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
    }

    filter {
         if [kubernetes] {
          mutate {
            add_field => {
              "container_name" => "%{[kubernetes][container][name]}"
              "namespace" => "%{[kubernetes][namespace]}"
              "pod" => "%{[kubernetes][pod][name]}"
            }
            replace => { "host" => "%{[kubernetes][node][name]}"}
          }
        }
        mutate {
          remove_field => ["tags"]
        }
    }

    output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug}
      loki {
        url => "http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki-benchmark.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you create the fields [kubernetes] and everyting below that. When your [kubernetes] field is not available container_name, namespace and pod are not created

Comment: @FredvN i have log generator pod is running, all are under common namespace.

Comment: @FredvN check this question for whole config.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74536583/logstash-with-loki-grafana-not-picking-all-the-kubernetes-pod-logs?noredirect=1#comment131573967_74536583

Comment: Even in the complete configuration I don't see where the kubernetes fields are added to the logmessage. With filebeat there is an autodiscover configuration (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html) but that is not available for logstash.

Comment: @FredvN what to do for logstash without filebeat, how it will identify the kubernetes fields.?

Comment: You can get some information from the filenames in /var/logs/containers. looks like <podname>_<namespace>_<contanername>_<containerid>.log. So create a filter in logstash to extract the information from the filename and add the fields to your message first and then apply your already created filter

Comment: @FredvN do you have any sample filter?