# logstash is not picking namespace, pod, container_name

Tags: logstash, grafana-loki

[image]

Below is my logastsh configuration. Grafana is unable to understand the namespace, pod, container_name send by logstash

```
input {
      file{
        path => "/host/var/log/pods/**/*.log"
        type => "kubernetes"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
    }
    filter {
     
        
        if \[kubernetes\] {
          mutate {
            add_field => {
              "container_name" => "%{\[kubernetes\]\[container\]\[name\]}"
              "namespace" => "%{\[kubernetes\]\[namespace\]}"
              "pod" => "%{\[kubernetes\]\[pod\]\[name\]}"
            }
            replace => { "host" => "%{\[kubernetes\]\[node\]\[name\]}"}
          }
        }
        mutate {
          remove_field => \["tags"\]
        }
      
    
    }

     output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug}
      loki {
        url => "http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki-benchmark.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555597/logstash-loki-logs-namespace-containers-pod-is-not-showing-properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [logstash loki logs namespace, containers, pod is not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555597/logstash-loki-logs-namespace-containers-pod-is-not-showing-properly)

Comment: @HarshManvar No